# OpenSearch Query Not Matching

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am trying to create a query that matches based off a file extension that is part of a key.

I know the following record exists in OpenSearch:

```
{
  '_index': 'the_index',
  '_type': 'some_type',
  '_id': 'id',
  '_score': 1,
  '_routing': 'routing',
  '_parent': 'parent',
  '_source': {
    'files': [
      {
        'bucket': 'a_bucket',
        'fileName': 'a_file_name.dat.gz',
        'size': 9001,
        'source': 's3://a_bucket/some_path/a_file_name.dat.gz',
        'key': 'some_path/a_file_name.dat.gz'
      },
      {
        'bucket': 'b_bucket',
        'fileName': 'a_file_name.dat.gz.ext.json',
        'size': 9001,
        'source': 's3://b_bucket/some_path/a_file_name.dat.gz.ext.json',
        'type': 'metadata',
        'key': 'some_path/a_file_name.dat.gz.ext.json'
      }
    ],
    'collectionId': 'collectionId',
    'status': 'completed',
    'timestamp': 1,
    'updatedAt': 1
  }
}
```

I can search files.key:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "files.key": {
              "query": "some_path/a_file_name.dat.gz.ext.json"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and it works correctly. If I remove any characters from the front it no longer returns results. So I tried a regex query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "files.key": ".*.ext.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Also returns no results.

What am I missing here? Some files.key values will start with s3://bucketname and some will end with ext.json and I need to find all of these records.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp` and `wildcard` queries work on *token* level, so you'd have to store your path as a `keyword` for those to work. However, it might still not return all the results because of the way ES handles wildcard queries (so query expansion won't cover all values).

The most correct way to go here would be using [path tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) (or even two of them - to split by `/` left-to-right and by `.` right-to-left). It might get quite complex, though, but you can try to get somewhat good result with a `bool` query with 2 `filter` clauses: one `match_phrase` for the prefix and one more for the suffix.